# Перехват сигнала с веб-камеры

Tags: c++builder, web-camera, c++

Здравствуйте. Я пришел с таким вот вопросом: нужно перехватить сигнал идущий с веб-камеры, обработать его и пропустить дальше. Все это в среде программирования C++ Builder 6.
Я понимаю что это достаточно объемная и не определенная тема, поэтому хотя бы просто посоветуйте мне что почитать, где бы описывались именно принципы работы с видеосигналом веб-камеры. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В своё время заинтересовался подобными компонентами:

http://www.mitov.com/products/videolab

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте!

А вообще-то было бы неплохо уточнить под какую операционную систему будете писать, т.к. есть подозрение, что API для работы с веб-камерой у разных версий Windows может отличаться.

Например, Вы можете использовать [WIA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663303.aspx) или [MediaCapture API](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622)

Comment: Писать буду под Windows 7, поэтому, судя по всему, WIA мне не подходит?

Comment: по всей видимости - как раз подходит